# Docker logs: npm self signed certificate error

Tags: docker, npm, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to Install Hyperledger composer on Mac OS by using [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) tutorial.

When I run the following command from tutorial

```
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 
0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card 
PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
```

When I check my Docker Logs. I have the following errors
  [image]

I would like to know is there a way I can pass .npmrc file to docker to solve this problem ?

Can I set NODE_TLS_Unauthorized=0 as environment variable and give it to Docker ?

Are there any work around solution from which i can solve the problem?

Notes:

1. I have provided .npmrc in the following command

   composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-
   network@0.0.1.bna -o npmrcFile=/Users/1/.npmrc
2. I have the following .npmrc file

   ```
   always-auth=true
   strict-ssl=false
   ca=
   loglevel=verbose
   proxy= myproxy
   https-proxy=myproxy
   unsafe-perm=true
   NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
   registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
   ```
3. I am running all the applications behind corporate firewall as well as in Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an npmrc file as part of the `composer network install` command. When fabric builds the chaincode image for the business network it will use that npmrc file as part of the npm install it performs, see
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information

for more information about the CLI options.

Comment: If you see my composer network install. I have provided my .npmrc as npmrcFile. Any more suggestions. It is able to pick up my proxy and download some npm packages.

Comment: By providing that npm rc entry on the install you are passing the npmrc file to the npm install command being run inside the docker environment. You could try running a local npm proxy in you intranet and then point to that server instead

Comment: Hi David_k, Is there a tutorial or something available for that? if possible can you provide me with some links. I will try to implement and update if it works

Comment: you can find info about verdaccio here, hopefully it has details about how to set it up and set your npmrc to point to it.  https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio. Other npm proxies are available of course, eg nexus

Comment: Thank you david for pointing me to right direction. I will try this out and let you know if it solves my problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can confirm that npmrc file was accepted by composer network command ? because when I give - O command to composer network start and give them npmrc.txt it is not able to find the path. but when I use -o and provide npmrcFile = path it does not throw the error.

Comment: the npmrc file option needs to be passed on install. if you specify the option and the file isn't found then the install should fail with an error